# Replace String Function With Capitalize Word

Tags: javascript

I need an explanation on below codes that I received on Stack Overflow.

```js
function sentenceCase(input, lowercaseBefore) {
    input = ( input === undefined || input === null ) ? '' : input;
    if (lowercaseBefore) { 
      input = input.toLowerCase(); 
    }
    return input.toString().replace( /(^|\. *)([a-z])/g,
    function(match, separator, char) {
        return separator + char.toUpperCase();
    });
}

var str = 'this is a text. hello world!';
str = sentenceCase(str);
document.write(str);
```

The code will make a string to capitalize after each dot(.) sign. Can someone explain how does the **replace function** works:

```
return input.toString().replace( /(^|\. *)([a-z])/g,
function(match, separator, char) {
    return separator + char.toUpperCase();
});
```

> **Update**

What is the content of `separator` and `char` on the replace function?

Comment: [MDN replace?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/tc6ZPE/2

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: Sorry @MikeMcCaughan  but i am confuse about the regular expression

Comment: Don't apologize, [edit] your question with an explanation of what you don't understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input = ( input === undefined || input === null ) ? '' : input;
```

Checks if input is empty or null

```
return input.toString().replace( /(^|\. *)([a-z])/g,
function(match, separator, char) {
    return separator + char.toUpperCase();
});
```

This uses a regex to match all the cases where a dot is followed by a lower case character, most notably

```
/(^|\. *)([a-z])/g
```

This looks first at the . then looks for any character between a-z right after it. Do note, that had they done [a-z][A-Z], the function would not work.

```
function(match, separator, char) {
    return separator + char.toUpperCase();
}
```

A simple lambda that just returns a to uppercase for the function inputs.

Update:

separator is the dot in this case, although it can be any delimiter that matches the regex function, and char is the next char after the separator is found.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I am a bit clear. What about the separator & char. Is the separator consist of the .?

Comment: Added an update @Amran. If you feel the answer satisfies what you wanted to know, please mark it as accepted